# Sending an e-mail with PNG images without losing image quality

Tags: email, images

I need to send an e-mail with screenshots in PNG format **without losing the quality** of the screenshots.

Outlook 2003 and 2010 converts the images copied from Word to **jpg** - and image quality is thus lost.

Thunderbird does the same thing.

I have tried different ways, but nothing seems to be working perfectly.

I am ready to write the message in **pure html**, attach png files (to have full control of the message and the images) - but Outlook does not give such possibility.

What is the best way to create an html e-mail with images and send it without losing image quality?

Answer (score 5):

What about copying out the image into (some graphic application) **irfanview** and saving it as PNG, and THEN attaching the file into your letter?

Answer (score 5):

The simple and short answer is: Make sure your images are saved as 96dpi. Read more here: http://www.howto-outlook.com/faq/unsharpimages.htm